# Is strategy 1 dominated, strictly or weakly, by strategy 2. How about by strategy 3?

Tags: game-theory

Consider the following voting game:

There are three candidates, each of whom chooses a position from the set $S_i
= \lbrace 1,
2,...,10 \rbrace$. The voters are equally distributed across these ten positions. This means at each position, there are 10% of the  available votes. Voters vote for
the candidate whose position is closest to theirs. If the three candidates are equidistant
from a given position, the voters at that position split their votes equally.
Thus, for example,
$u_1(8, 8,8) = 33.3$ ( this means the candidate $1$ choosing position $8$ with other two candidates also choosing position $8$ will  get about 33.3% of the total available votes, and similarly $u_1(7,9,9) = 73.3$.

Now the problem is

**Is strategy $1$ dominated, strictly or weakly, by
strategy $2$? How about by strategy $3$?
By "strategy $1$", I mean the strategy of choosing position $1$. Similarly for others.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the question, because you got $u_1(7,9,9)$ right, so why not just compute the rest of the probabilities $u_n(i,j,k)$ where $i,j,k$ is ordered with repetitions and notice who wins/ties given $i,j,k$? That way I got this table

$$\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
 \text{} & 1 \\
\hline
 1 & 2 \\
\hline
 \text{1  2} & 3 \\
\hline
 \text{1  2  3} & \text{4  10} \\
\hline
 \text{1  2  10} & 5 \\
\hline
 \text{1  9  10} & 6 \\
\hline
 \text{8  9  10} & \text{1  7} \\
\hline
 \text{9  10} & 8 \\
\hline
 10 & 9 \\
\hline
 \text{} & 10 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
If in row $R$, column $C$ we have number $N$, it means that $N$ is dominated by $R$ (weakly if $C = 2$, strictly if $C = 1$)

Comment: Can you please explain what your table means? I don't really understand.

Comment: @PropositionX The rows index $1,2,\ldots,10$ correspond to the strategy dominating other strategies. You see e.g. in row 4 that strategy 1 is dominated by 4. So is strategy 2, 3, and weakly 10. So if a candidate goes for strategy 1,2,3 he is doomed if someone else goes for strategy 4.

Comment: I still don't follow. In row $4$, you have $1,2,3,10$. What does that even mean?

Comment: @PropositionX It means that all of strategy 1,2,3,10 are dominated by strategy 4